# Enumerar registros en mysql si perder enumeración al ordenar la tabla

Tags: mysql

Hola estoy tratando de mantener un orden de enumeración de una consulta sin alterarse cuando ordeno los datos, pero no he podido hacerlo, al agregar ORDER BY la enumeración cambia por completo.

Como quiero que se vea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve al ordenarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber cómo mantener el orden de mayor a menor sin alterarse al ordenar los datos.

Espero puedan ayudarme con una solución.

Agrego consulta para ser mas claro:

```
SELECT
 id,
 r.total,
 ( @row_number := @row_number + 1 ) AS row_num 
FROM
 test as r,
 ( SELECT @row_number := 0 ) AS temp 
INNER JOIN other_test as ov on ov.clae in ('rows')
WHERE 
 r.id = ov.id_test
ORDER BY
 r.total
```

si ejecuto el QUERY sin el ORDER BY lo hace bien pero cuando ordeno muestra la primera tabla que envie.

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo el order by primero por el campo "orden" y luego por los otros?, Por favor muestra tu SELECT en la pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por lo que comentas, necesitas añadir una variable que actúe como contador: `set @i=0; SELECT *,@i:=@i+1 FROM...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordena primero en una subconsulta y después agregas la enumeración:

```
SELECT t.*
     , @row_number := @row_number + 1 row_num
  FROM ( SELECT r.id
              , r.total
           FROM test r
             INNER JOIN other_test ov 
               ON ov.id_test = r.id
           WHERE ov.clae in ('rows')
           ORDER BY r.total
       ) t
     , ( SELECT @row_number := 0 ) v
```

Si tienes MySQL 8:

```
SELECT r.id
     , r.total
     , row_number() OVER( ORDER BY r.total ) row_num
  FROM test r
    INNER JOIN other_test ov 
      ON ov.id_test = r.id
  WHERE ov.clae in ('rows')
```

Comment: Irónicamente, cuando vi tu respuesta, entendí la pregunta.